# Proving divisibility of a sum $\sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor{n/2}\rfloor} (-1)^{k}\binom{n}{2k} 7^{k}$

Tags: binomial-coefficients, divisibility, recursion

I have been given $$
\sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor{n/2}\rfloor} (-1)^{k}\binom{n}{2k} 7^{k}
$$. How can I show that it is divisible by $2^{n - 1}$ for any positive integer $n$? I have attempted to write it in terms $$
\sum_{k=0}^{n} i^{k}\binom{n}{k} \frac{1+(-1)^k}{2}7^{k} = ... = \frac{1}{2}[(1+7i)^n + (1-7i)^n]
$$ but I am stuck. I think there might be some recursion pattern but I am not sure. Any hints?

EDIT:

I have rewritten the above expression using complex numbers, so the 2nd expression is now equal to the first

Comment: Your first step is a good one! If you separate that second sum into two sums, can you evaluate each one exactly using the binomial theorem?

Comment: Yes I did it in an attempt to separate it into two sums but I have encountered the problem that (-1)^k will change sign for every other term, leaving me with my initial series but with all the terms having a positive sign! How can I work around this issue? What I mean is that my second sum is not equal to the first sum because the negative signs have disappeared...

Comment: if anyone has any suggestions on how to use complex numbers for this case (I got this idea after reading a few posts by other users), it would be good too because I don't quite fully understand it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can write the sum in closed form as
\begin{align*}
\color{blue}{\sum_{k=0}^{\left\lfloor\frac{n}{2}\right\rfloor}(-1)^k\binom{n}{2k}7^k}
&=\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}\left(i\sqrt{7}\right)^k\frac{1+(-1)^k}{2}\\
&\color{blue}{=\frac{1}{2}(1+i\sqrt{7})^n+\frac{1}{2}(1-i\sqrt{7})^n}
\end{align*}
We want to show that for $n\geq 1$
\begin{align*}
2^{n-1} \Bigg| \left(\frac{1}{2}(1+i\sqrt{7})^n+\frac{1}{2}(1-i\sqrt{7})^n\right)
\end{align*}

We show equivalently for $n\geq 1$
\begin{align*}
\color{blue}{a_n:=\frac{1}{2^n}(1+i\sqrt{7})^n+\frac{1}{2^n}(1-i\sqrt{7})^n\in\mathbb{Z}}\tag{1}
\end{align*}
We give a proof by induction on $n$.

**Base step:**

We obtain for $n=1$ and $n=2$:
\begin{align*}
\color{blue}{a_1}&=\frac{1}{2}(1+i\sqrt{7})+\frac{1}{2}(1-i\sqrt{7})\color{blue}{=1\in\mathbb{Z}}\\
\color{blue}{a_2}&=\frac{1}{2^2}(1+i\sqrt{7})^2+\frac{1}{2^2}(1-i\sqrt{7})^2\\
&=\frac{1}{4}\left(1+2i\sqrt{7}-7\right)+\frac{1}{4}\left(1-2i\sqrt{7}-7\right)\\
&\color{blue}{=-3\in\mathbb{Z}}
\end{align*}

**Induction hypothesis: $n=N$**

We assume the validity of
\begin{align*}
\color{blue}{a_N}=\frac{1}{2^N}(1+i\sqrt{7})^N+\frac{1}{2^N}(1-i\sqrt{7})^N\color{blue}{\in\mathbb{Z}}
\end{align*}

**Induction step: $n=N+1$**
\begin{align*}
\color{blue}{a_{N+1}}&=\frac{1}{2^{N+1}}(1+i\sqrt{7})^{N+1}+\frac{1}{2^{N+1}}(1-i\sqrt{7})^{N+1}\\
&=\frac{1}{2^{N-1}}(1+i\sqrt{7})^{N-1}\frac{1}{4}(1+i\sqrt{7})^2
+\frac{1}{2^{N-1}}(1-i\sqrt{7})^{N-1}\frac{1}{4}(1-i\sqrt{7})^2\\
&=\frac{1}{2^{N-1}}(1+i\sqrt{7})^{N-1}\frac{1}{4}(-6+2i\sqrt{7})
+\frac{1}{2^{N-1}}(1-i\sqrt{7})^{N-1}\frac{1}{4}(-6-2i\sqrt{7})\\
&=\frac{1}{2^{N-1}}(1+i\sqrt{7})^{N-1}\frac{1}{2}(-3+i\sqrt{7})
+\frac{1}{2^{N-1}}(1-i\sqrt{7})^{N-1}\frac{1}{2}(-3-i\sqrt{7})\\
&=\frac{1}{2^{N-1}}(1+i\sqrt{7})^{N-1}\left(\frac{1}{2}(1+i\sqrt{7})-2\right)\\
&\qquad+\frac{1}{2^{N-1}}(1-i\sqrt{7})^{N-1}\left(\frac{1}{2}(1-i\sqrt{7})-2\right)\\
&\color{blue}{=a_{N}-2a_{N-1}\in\mathbb{Z}}
\end{align*}
and the claim (1) follows.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: try to use the identity $\binom{n}{k} = \binom{n-1}{k} + \binom{n-1}{k-1}$. If you apply this in your sum, you'll get $\binom{n}{2k} = \binom{n-1}{2k} + \binom{n-1}{2k-1}$. Its enough, because it contains all coefficient's denominators: even and odd. And I would put also together $(-1)^k \cdot 7^k$ to get $(-7)^k$

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Let $\alpha=\frac{1}{2}(1+ \sqrt{-7})$ and $\beta=\frac{1}{2}(1-\sqrt{-7})$.

Note that $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are algebraic integers.
(Consider $x^2-x+2\in \mathbb{Q}[x]$)

So $\alpha^n$ and $\beta^n$ are also algebraic integers.

Thus $\alpha^n+\beta^n$ is algebraic integer.

Since $\alpha^n+\beta^n\in \mathbb{Q}$ and $\alpha^n+\beta^n$ is algebraic integer, $\alpha^n+\beta^n$ is integer.

Therefore your expression is divisible by $2^{n-1}$.